# Properly install Java 9 along with Java 8

Tags: java, netbeans

How do you properly install java 9 along with java 8.  I'm currently using Java 8 and Netbeans for a class, but I would like to have the ability to experiment with code using the new JShell.  I just don't want to mess up my Netbeans configuration or any other JRE by installing Java 9.  How can I do it safely and not disturb Netbeans and my current JRE?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can give [jEnv](http://www.jenv.be/) a try. It's a Java version manager (similar to those available in Ruby, Node etc). It allows you to switch between Java versions (locally, per project, per terminal etc). All the aliases are installed in ~/.jenv directory and will not impact you current working environment.

Once installed you can run Java9 just for current terminal session with `jenv shell 9`

Comment: jEnv is a very slick tool!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the latest NetBeans Development IDE, which is downloadable from here:[NetBeans Dowload](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) , installing it alongside NetBeans 8.2, for example, is easy as it will autodetect Java JDK 9 (assuming you have installed it) and import your existing settings.
In my case I found that you can't add the Java 9 platform to NetBeans 8.2. You have to install the JDK and then install the NetBeans Development build. Once installed you can use it to create modular projects and use Jshell.